# Python Post call throwing 400 Bad Request using requests library

Tags: python-3.x, post, python-requests

I am writing a python script which will POST to an endpoint but for some reason, I am getting 400 Bad Request. I am not sure what I am missing here. My code is as below : Updated code to include referer, still, I am getting the same error. I have kept referal URL same as the post URL

```
import requests
import csv
import simplejson
import json
url = 'https://xyz.io/v1/candidates'
headers = {'content-type': 'application/json',
       'On-Behalf-Of':'{334401}',
       'Authorization':'Ommited'
       'referer': 'https://xyz.io/v1/candidates'
       }
data={
  "first_name": "IamTest",
  "last_name": "IamTest"
}
response = requests.post(url,data=data,headers=headers)
print(response)
print(response.reason)
```

Answer (score 0):

Most sites will reject the request if you don't have an origin and referer header, also use chrome developer tools and when hitting the login button look at the post request and send the post request to that URL. Also some sites will send a `400` response code if the login creds aren't right.

```
import requests
import csv
import simplejson
import json


url = 'https://xyz.io/v1/candidates'

headers = {
       'content-type': 'application/json',
       'On-Behalf-Of':'{334401}',
       'Authorization':'Ommited',
       'referer': 'https://xyz.io/v1/candidates',
       'origin' : 'homepage of the site', #ex: 'https://www.instagram.com'
       'referer' : 'login page of the site'
       }
data = {
      "first_name": "IamTest",
      "last_name": "IamTest"
}

response = requests.post(url,data=data,headers=headers)

print(response)
print(response.reason)
```

Comment: Thanks for answering but I am a newbie in python so I didn't actually get what you are trying to say. Could you please re-post my code with correct syntax

Comment: @AshishVerma did this answer your question